# Loop until Animation finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for an way to loop a function as long as an animation is executed.

The reason is: I created an [UI-Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos/container.html) within a parent div. The parent div changes it's width due to an animation. The problem is that the UI-Layout doesn't adjust to the parent's width.

By calling `$(window).trigger('resize');` when the animation is finished the UI Layout adjusts to the new width.
But I now want the layout to adjust smoothly to the animation so that the UI-Layout grows in an animated way (just like the parent div).

So my idea was to loop `$(window).trigger('resize');` as long as the animation of the width of the parent div is playing.

What is the best way to loop a function while the animation is playing?
Or are there better ways to achieve what I am looking for?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please share the code with which you initiate the animation.

Comment: Is the animation a CSS animation or jQuery animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`.animate(properties, options)`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) syntax, which allows you to listen to the progress event.

Example:

```
$( "#book" ).animate({
    width: "+=50px" // whatever CSS properties that are animated...
}, {
    duration: 500,
    progress: function() { // This gets called several times during the animation
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }
    complete: function() {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }
});
```

#### CSS transitions

If you are using pure CSS transitions, then right after you launch the transition, you could call this function, passing it the element that is being animated:

```
function manageResize(elem) {
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }, 50);
    elem.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }, false);
}
```

This will resize the window every few milliseconds (adjust as needed) and stop doing that once the transition comes to an end.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery animation, a way would be:

```
var animating = true;
$( elem ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
}, 5000, function() {
    animating = false;
});

var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(animating)
       $(window).trigger('resize');
    else
       clearInterval(timer);
},50);
```

Or, if you're using CSS animation:

```
// start animation
var animating = true;
$( elem ).addClass("animating");
$( elem ).one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
    function(event) {
    animating = false;
});

var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(animating)
       $(window).trigger('resize');
    else
       clearInterval(timer);
},50);
```

Comment: Not possible. Your callback will never execute while you are looping. You have a single UI thread.

Comment: Where would you trigger the resize event?

Comment: in the while loop. The animate and CSS animation would immediately return and they'll run in another thread.

Comment: If you want to try it, you may animate 10 elements in a loop, they will start at the same time.

Comment: So you are going to block the browser during the duration of the whole animation in a busy `while` loop?

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the comment "do whatever you want here" and add the trigger event. You may resolve this by setinterval either.

Comment: Ok, this answer works as the OP asks, but no one will care taking back their downvotes because they answered too. Wonderful.